# How to access data from the toggle buttons saved through provider

Tags: flutter, dart, provider, togglebutton, flutter-change-notifier

```
I am saving toggle button data and adding the toggle button 
data list through provider in the list of Flatdetail1. the code 
is

class FormDetail1 extends StatefulWidget {
  const FormDetail1({Key? key, required this.onNext}) : super(key: key);
  final VoidCallback onNext;
  @override
  State<FormDetail1> createState() => _FormDetail1State();
}

class _FormDetail1State extends State<FormDetail1> {
  List<bool> isSelected = [false, false, false];
  List<bool> isSelected1 = [false, false, false, false];
  List<bool> isSelected2 = [false, false, false];
  String city = '';
  String city1 = '';
  String city2 = '';

  var saveFlatDetail = FlatDetail1(
    id1: '',
    id2: '',
    id3: '',
  );

  void saveData() {
    Provider.of<BasicInfo>(context, listen: false).addDetails1(saveFlatDetail);
    print(saveFlatDetail.id1);
    print(saveFlatDetail.id2);
    print(saveFlatDetail.id3);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //final flatDetail = Provider.of<FlatDetail1>(context);
    print('hello sir ');
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Flutter App'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Center(
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(50.0),
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  ToggleButtons(
                    isSelected: isSelected,
                    children: [
                      Text('India'),
                      Text('Nepal'),
                      Text('China'),
                    ],
                    onPressed: (int newIndex) {
                      setState(() {
                        for (int i = 0; i < isSelected.length; i++) {
                          isSelected[i] = i == newIndex;
                        }
                        if (newIndex == 0) {
                          city = 'India';
                        } else if (newIndex == 1) {
                          city = 'Nepal';
                        } else if (newIndex == 2) {
                          city = 'china';
                        }
                        saveFlatDetail = FlatDetail1(
                          id1: city,
                          id2: saveFlatDetail.id2,
                          id3: saveFlatDetail.id3,
                        );
                        // flatDetail.updateValue(city);
                        // print(city);
                      });
                    },
                  ),
                  ToggleButtons(
                    isSelected: isSelected1,
                    children: [
                      Text('UP'),
                      Text('MP'),
                      Text('Bihar'),
                      Text('Odisha'),
                    ],
                    onPressed: (int newIndex1) {
                      setState(() {
                        for (int i = 0; i < isSelected1.length; i++) {
                          isSelected1[i] = i == newIndex1;
                        }
                        if (newIndex1 == 0) {
                          city1 = 'UP';
                        } else if (newIndex1 == 1) {
                          city1 = 'MP';
                        } else if (newIndex1 == 2) {
                          city1 = 'Bihar';
                        } else if (newIndex1 == 3) {
                          city1 = 'Odisha';
                        }
                        saveFlatDetail = FlatDetail1(
                          id1: saveFlatDetail.id1,
                          id2: city1,
                          id3: saveFlatDetail.id3,
                        );
                        // flatDetail.updateValue(city1);
                        // print(city1);
                      });
                    },
                  ),
                  Container(
                    color: Colors.red[50],
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                    child: ToggleButtons(
                      isSelected: isSelected2,
                      children: [
                        Text('Patna'),
                        Text('Delhi'),
                        Text('Lucknow'),
                      ],
                      onPressed: (int newIndex2) {
                        setState(() {
                          for (int i = 0; i < isSelected2.length; i++) {
                            isSelected2[i] = i == newIndex2;
                          }
                          if (newIndex2 == 0) {
                            city2 = 'Patna';
                          } else if (newIndex2 == 1) {
                            city2 = 'Delhi';
                          } else if (newIndex2 == 2) {
                            city2 = 'Lucknow';
                          }
                          saveFlatDetail = FlatDetail1(
                            id1: saveFlatDetail.id1,
                            id2: saveFlatDetail.id2,
                            id3: city2,
                          );
                      
                        });
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 100),
                  GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                      saveData();

                      if (city == '' || city1 == '' || city2 == '') {
                        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                          SnackBar(
                            content: Text(
                              'Please select all',
                            ),
                            duration: Duration(milliseconds: 400),
                          ),
                        );
                      } else {
                        widget.onNext();
                      }
                    },
                    child: Container(
                      height: 40,
                      width: 125,
                      color: Colors.blue,
                      child: Text('Widget Playground!'),
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 40,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Now i want to access id1,id2 and id3 in a text field but not
able to access it, here is the code below

```
    class BasicInfo extends ChangeNotifier {
      List<FlatDetail1> _details1 = [
        FlatDetail1(
          id1: '',
          id2: '',
          id3: '',
        ),
      ];
    
      List<FlatDetail1> get details1 {
        return [..._details1];
      }
    
      void addDetails1(FlatDetail1 flatDetail) {
        final newFlatDetail = FlatDetail1(
          id1: flatDetail.id1,
          id2: flatDetail.id2,
          id3: flatDetail.id3,
        );
        _details1.add(newFlatDetail);
        notifyListeners();
      }
    }
```

When i use  Text(name.details1['id1']), it shows error i also used name.details[index].id1 but still no use.Please tell me how to access the id1,id2,id3.

```
 class FormDetail2 extends StatefulWidget {
  const FormDetail2({Key? key, required this.onNext}) : super(key: key);
  final VoidCallback onNext;

  @override
  State<FormDetail2> createState() => _FormDetail2State();
}

class _FormDetail2State extends State<FormDetail2> {
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    
    final name = Provider.of<BasicInfo>(context);
    //print(name.id1);
    
    return Scaffold(
      
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Text(name.details1[].id1),
            
            Text(''),
            Text(''),
          ],
         
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

this is the code and i wwant to access id1,id2,id3 in
FormDetail2 page

Comment: show the code as a code not a image

Comment: i have updated the code,please have a look @MrShakila , thanks